How to pass extra parameters to an LLM?
I want to pass some additional properties in the input object passed to the LLM model, beyond those produced by the ChatPromptTemplate. I need to call my LLM with a Json object, which in addition to the messages property needs some other properties. I could create a custom LLM but it seems the invoke method of an LLM expects a string parameter. Can I pass a serialized Json object which contains both messages (prompt) and my extra parameters?
